# How to replace recursively part of file name in bash

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I have a directory having subdirectories containing images files with a wrong name such like filename.jpg.jpg i want to replace this recursiveley with filename.jpg
i have tried:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/string1/string2/g' {} \;
```

or

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' *
```

but none works

thank you

Comment: I suggest you use the `rename` tool, it is quite powerful for bulk renaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find ./ -iname "*.jpg.jpg" -exec rename .jpg.jpg .jpg '{}' \;
```

If you have a `rename` utility which uses perl regular expressions, then use the below command :

```
find ./ -iname "*.jpg.jpg" -exec rename 's/\.jpg\.jpg$/.jpg/' '{}' \;
```

Comment: I'm getting the following here:
`syntax error at (eval 1) line 1, near "."`

Comment: @volpato: Sorry, what is that all about?

Comment: @volpato: Do you have a `rename` command (Ubuntu) which uses Perl regular expressions? In that case you might need to change the `rename` part to `rename 's/\.jpg\.jpg$/.jpg/'`

Answer (score 1):

May be you could use the inbuilt `rename` command.

```
rename 's/\.jpg\.jpg$/.jpg/' *.jpg.jpg
```

The first argument is a regular expression that would **match** filenames ending  in `.jpg.jpg` and replace with `.jpg`.
The second argument will **look** for files with `.jpg.jpg` format in the current directory.

For more info, read the man page.

Comment: Is it limited to the current folder?

Comment: No. You can provide path of the folder to search files.