# How to rename all *.json files in folders by inserting a string before file extension .json?

Tags: batch-file

I have JSON files in different folders inside `apps\*.json`.

How to rename all of them by adding a suffix to the name?

`a.json` to `a_file.json`
`b.json` to `b_file.json`

Below is what I tried, but it is not producing the expected file names.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.json') do (
    ren "%%i" "_file.json" 
)
```

And how can I undo this operation?

`a_file.json` to `a.json`

Comment: Try this  > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753012/how-to-replace-recursively-part-of-file-name-in-bash/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following *commented* batch script should do both:

- **add** `_file` suffix if a non-empty parameter is supplied, and
- **remove** `_file` suffix  if a no parameter is supplied

(even in all subfolders if specified `dir /b /S` instead of  `dir /b`):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

::: change  next 3 lines to match current circumstances: 
set "suffix=_file"                                       suffix to add/remove
set "extens=json"                                        file extension
set "folder=D:\test\SO\46404782"                         working directory

::: set working directory
pushd "%folder%"

if "%~1"=="" (
    rem reverse
    for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b *%suffix%.%extens% 2^>NUL') do (
        set "newname=%%~G"
        set "newname=!newname:%suffix%.%extens%=.%extens%!"
        ECHO ren "%%~fG" "!newname!"
    )
) else (
    rem add suffix
    for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b *.%extens% 2^>NUL') do (
        ECHO ren "%%~fG" "%%~nG%suffix%%%~xG"
    )
)

popd
```

Note that productive `ren` command is merely displayed using `ECHO` for debugging purposes.

**Sample output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\46404782.bat
ren "D:\test\SO\46404782\c_file.json" "c.json"

==> D:\bat\SO\46404782.bat 1
ren "D:\test\SO\46404782\a.json" "a_file.json"
ren "D:\test\SO\46404782\b.json" "b_file.json"
ren "D:\test\SO\46404782\c_file.json" "c_file_file.json"

==>
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~nG`, `%~xG`, `%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`!newname:%suffix%.%extens%=.%extens%!` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution for appending `_file` is running in command prompt window:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b *.json') do @ren "%i" "%~ni_file.json"
```

In a batch file `%` must be escaped with one more percent sign:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.json') do @ren "%%i" "%%~ni_file.json"
```

`%~ni` or `%%~ni` references the file name without file extension and without path as explained by the help output on running in a command prompt window `for /?`.

Use additionally **DIR** option `/s` to process recursively all *.json files in current directory and all its subdirectories.